# useRef is sometimes undefined even tho value exists

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm trying to keep a previous value that is constantly updated through my store using the useRef hook as below, however, the ref value is sometimes undefined even tho I am only setting it when the value exists.

```
const price = useSelector(getPrice(props.index));
let prevPriceRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
        if(price) {
            prevPriceRef.current = price;
        }
    }, [ price ])
```

console.log(prevPriceRef.current) sometimes returns undefined, who is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes or all the time?

Comment: Sometimes. I would think that the if condition would prevent setting the ref's value to undefined if the price that is returned is undefined. Event tho is in never the case.

Comment: The initial value of useRef is undefined, isn't it?

Comment: Until the first time `prevPriceRef.current = price` is called, `prevPriceRef.current` is undefined. If the component is unmounted, then mounted again, the ref is also undefined initially until the useEffect functions runs for the first time. So it really depends on where and when you log the value and what the ultimate goal is here.

Comment: yes, but that is not my issue here. if I console log price, it is always defined, but then prevPriceRef.current will still be undefined when I console.log it some of the times

Comment: Why not make the previous price a part of your store? Just update it whenever price is going to change.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate hook to handle/record previous value

```js
function usePrevious(value) {

  const ref = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); 

  return ref.current;
}
```

Use it by calling

```
const prevPrice = usePrevious(price);
```

---

One thing to note, you are checking for `if (price) {}` which will not execute if your price is `0` => Zero and will return undefined as you will not be setting the current value to the ref.